# Table using Latex in overleaf shows at the bottom of the table

Tags: floats

Despite specifiyin that the table should show where it is place in the code `\begin{table}[ht]` it shows at the bottom of the document. I am using Latex in overleaf.

Here is what I try:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Example of profit developments}
    \label{tab:table3}
    \begin{tabular}{llrrrrr}
    \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Case 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Case 2} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
    & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Constant\\ mark-up assumption\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Increasing\\ mark-up assumption\end{tabular}}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    & {\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}National\\Accounts Indicators\end{tabular}} & {\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Initial Period\\ T0\end{tabular}} & T1 & {\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\%Change from\\ T0 to T1\end{tabular}} & T1 & {\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\%Change from\\ T0 to T1\end{tabular}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    (1) & Mark-up &20\%&20\% &0\% &15\% &-25\% \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    (2) & Real units & & & & & \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    (3) & Intermediate costs & & & & & \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    (4) & Labour costs & & & & & \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    (5) & Total costs = (3) + (4) & & & & & \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    (6) & Profits & & & & & \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    (7) & Nominal gross output = (5) + (6) & & & & & \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    (8) & Unit profits = (6) / (2) & & & & & \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    (9) & Price = (7) / (2) & & & & & \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    (10) & Profit share = (6) / [(6) + (4)] & & & & & \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
      \\Source: US Bureau of Economic Analysis
      \end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

Comment: `\begin{table}[h!]` prevents the table being placed at the top or bottom of the page or on a page of tabvles, so  gives latex very few places to place it, normallty it generates a warning and is changed to `ht`

Comment: May I ask what the use of the `minipage` is for? That does not seem to do anything.

Comment: aways include `p` in the options, try `[htp]` then it should come earlier

Comment: If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/77831489/2777074